# How to increase the responding time for ReQL query in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

By now I've 1Million records in my table. When I trying to add a new column/variable to the table it is showing time out error.I even tried to limit the data intake but it doesn't. Can anyone tell me how to tackel it. Any help would be appreaciable.

```
e: HTTP ReQL query timed out after 300 seconds in:
r.table("interestdata").update({"pick": 0});
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [rethink tutorial](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/connect/) we can increase the connection timeout using javascript or python etc.

```
r.connect({
host: 'localhost',
port: 28015,
db: 'test',
timeout:600
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't this only affect just the connection setup? Did this really fix the reql timeout itself for you? (I got the same problem, a 100 million document table I need to do changes to which needless to say takes more than 300 seconds :)